# Non-blinking block-cursor in Windows XP command-prompt?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, console, windows-command-prompt

**Purpose**

I normally work in many UNIX-like environments using Xterm. I have grown fond of the [non-blinking block-cursor](http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/os/Linux/doc/LDP/linuxfocus/common/images2/article364/xterm.png) it uses. In fact, I have grown so accustomed to it (especially in Vi) that it has become difficult to edit without it. Now that I am working with Windows XP... well, you get the idea.

**Question**

Does anyone know any program, command, registry entry, ANSI escape sequence, or technique to get the aforementioned cursor in the standard Windows XP command-prompt (cmd.exe)? Using alternatives (such as Console) is not possible in the environment I am working in.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can adjust the cursor blink rate, width, etc via accessibility options in the control panel.  This might get you the desired effect you're looking for.  Take a look here:**

http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/blinkrate.aspx

My recommendation would be that you set blink rate to NONE and then make the cursor wider to achieve your "block" look.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Interestingly, changing the width of the cursor in Accessibility Options doesn't have any impact on cmd.exe! It changes it for most Windows applications, but (for some reason) the change does not show up in the command-prompt... weird!

Comment: In the cmd.exe window try clicking PROPERTIES and selecting LARGE cursor size.  That will turn it into a block.  If you like the way that looks simply change the default.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using **Console** instead. Not only can it change the cursor into a block cursor, it also support tabbing *and* dynamically resizable window (i.e., drag the corners instead of going into a dialog box).

Get it here: [Console at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)

Answer (score 0):

[No Blink Accelerator](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/noblink.html) seems to be able to do what you want.

Comment: I have actually explored this option in the past. It disables the blink just fine, but (for some reason) doesn't transform the cursor into a block. I'll experiment some more and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command in Cmd and restart Cmd:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v CursorBlinkRate /t REG_SZ /d -1 /f
```

This will set the the value of Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` value `CursorBlinkRate` to -1. Which will stop Command Prompt cursor blinking.

Answer (score -2):

1.
Open Command Prompt 
2.
Right-click the title bar, and do one of the following:
•
To change this setting for all command prompt windows, click Defaults.
•
To change this setting for the current command prompt window only, click Properties.
3.
On the Options tab, under Cursor Size, specify a cursor size.

Comment: This does not address the *blinking* indicated in the OP.